# Import trouble in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Imagine the following project structure

```
app/
    foo/
        __init__.py
        a.py
        b.py
```

In *a.py* i have class **A** which uses class **B** from *b.py* file, and **B** class from *b.py* uses **A** class form *a.py*

if I write:

```
from foo.b import B
```

in *a.py* and

```
from foo.a import A
```

in *b.py*, the recursion occurs

How can I do properly import, without merging **A** and **B** in single file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python doesn't support circular imports, partly because they are usually a symptom of a flawed design.

What you can do is make `A` and `B` self-contained and reference both of them from a third file, or alternatively, extract the shared structure into a third fileand reference that from both your modules. How exactly this is going to work highly depends on what `A` and `B` are and why you think they should know of each other.

For example, you could make `A` just take a reference to an instance of `B` via its constructor, that way you won't need an import:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b
    # .. some methods that reference self.b
```

It gets a bit more complicated if inheritance is involved. In that case, you probably don't want the superclass to know of the subclass, because that would violate the [substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: I have something like tree structure.
For example A - is the root element and B is its children (children are instances of B) So A object has to know his children, and childen has to now his child.

Comment: @atom: That's not really helpful. In a hierarchy, the parent usually doesn't need to know their exact children's types. In other programming languages, you would use abstract classes or interfaces to build up the type structure. In Python, the preferred way is to just use duck typing.

Comment: @Rohit: I was hoping the rest of the answer is much more helpful than this single buzz word

Comment: @NiklasB.. Haha.. thats not actually my fault, neither yours.. Actually this single buzz word only i didn't knew.. Didn't knew that we call it Substitution principle..

Comment: @atom: You are wrong there. The parent doesn't need to know the exact type of its children, only their common interface. In Python, this is basically the set of methods they respond to, which is implicitly available without any imports.

Comment: I understand but in my case unfortunately I need cross references. 
The object are wrappers for DB data and general future is when I reference to object field and get not its Id but real object instance.

For example DbPost Object has method getAuthor() which returns DbAuthor, not its Id. For this i need DbAuthor be imported to DbPost module for creating instance by DbAutor's id. And DbAuthor has method getPosts() which returns list of DbPosts instances

Comment: @atom: You should read up on the [abstract factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern), which can be used to avoid this kind of tight coupling. I don't see in your description why `DbAuthor` would need to create references of `DbPost`, so it doesn't need to import `DbPost`. But in general, you shouldn't create instances of your data objects by calling constructors at all! You should have a dedicated data storage object that acts as a factory for creating the objects (or fetching them from the DB and creating a wrapper). Just look at sqlalchemy or other ORM systems

Comment: @Niklas B. OK, I'll read, but looking ahead I'll ask you question, if will be some factory, it will import DbAuthor and DbPost, and DbAuthor and DbPost will import this factory. Does not this the same issue?

Comment: @atomAltera: No, they don't need to now the type of the factory, only its interface (which is implicit because Python has duck typing). In particular, they don't need to create instances of the factory. They are given a reference to the factory via their constructor (or via dependency injection etc.)